# Install npm packages locally to be accesed by other projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, maven, npm

I'd like to know how it works npm comparing to Maven (I come from a Java background) in terms of managing packages.
I have created a generic component using Angular 4, this component will be used in many projects. So, I have published it to our nexus registry and then, from the client projects I just import the package so that the package gets downloaded from the registry and everything works fine.

Now, for development, I don't want to be publishing to the registry every single time I do a modification in the generic component and rebuilding the clients. 
I would like instead to do it like we do with Maven in Java, we install the artifact in our local repo, and the artifact will be picked up from the local repo before going to the global 'artifactory', but I see that when we install a module using npm, it gets installed inside node_modules folder inside the same project, so that the module is not available for any other project.

How should I do that? In other words, does npm keep a local repository where the installed modules are accessible to any other projects without the need of publishing to the global registry?

Thanks

Comment: So let's be clear on one thing first there is a big difference between package handling in Java and front end i.e in your case angular 4.Since the front end applications need to be loaded at the client side they may need their own packages.There are case where the files you are using may be pre-cached int client machine then the web pages will use a shared package.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is either installing it Globally so it can be accessed anywhere on that machine or if your project structure could support 1 central node_modules instead of per project basis.

Comment: So in DEV, for every modification in the package I need to first update it globally, and rebuild the client project which has the dependency to the package to test the changes. I assume that if the package is installed globally in the machine, it takes it first from there before downloading from the registry? Is that right? something similar to maven...

Answer (score 0):

use --global switch behind the npm install command to install the package of your choice global.

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

To make something available to the rest of the system's node package environment through npm, you can install it globally *(which is local to your **system**)* rather than locally *(which is local to your **project**)*. You can see documentation for global-ness on installs in [this part](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally) of the NPM documentation.

`npm i -g package names here`

`npm install --global package names here`

You can update your globally installed packages as you would a locally installed one as well when you need to.

`npm update -g package names here`

*(or all of them without specifying)*

`npm update -g`

See the full [NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/) pages for more detailed flags, etc.

---

If you're hoping to use your own packages in a managed environment, you can either [publish them as private modules](https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro) or keep them in a VCS (mostly git) and reference them by the appropriate method for that VCS in your projects' package.json scheme through the dependencies block for [github urls](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls) or more generally [other git hosts](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies), like

    `"dependencies": {
        "myComponent": "user/repo#feature\/branch",
        "otherComponent": "git+https://myGitHost.tld/.../projectName.git#commit"
    }`

Comment: So in DEV, for every modification in the package I need to first update it globally, and rebuild the client project which has the dependency to the package to test the changes. I assume that if the package is installed globally in the machine, it takes it first from there before downloading from the registry? Is that right? something similar to maven...

Comment: NPM [has a caching system](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache) built in that holds copies of recently used (or all) versions of packages - which should prevent most unnecessary network traffic if that's your concern.

To be clear, it's somewhat bad practice to install something globally if you intend to use it for a project - global installs are the preferred way of introducing new node-based or node-related command line tools into your system. "Installed globally" has a different meaning to the cache - I wrote about it because you used those words in asking.

Comment: You should \*generally\* be fine to just install the latest available version of your package and let NPM take care of figuring out what that actually means.